# Implement Async validator on Angular FormControl

Tags: angular

I followed the short guide on Angular's website for Creating asynchronous validators that can be found at this url.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator

As a result, I have this code:

```
import { AsyncValidator, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CompanyService } from '../services/company/company.service';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' });

export class UniqueCompanyNameValidator implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) { }

  validate(
    ctrl: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.companyService.CheckName(ctrl.value).pipe(
      map(isTaken => (isTaken ? { uniqueCompanyName: true } : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}
```

How do I add into my form control to actually use this custom validator? I tried to import the validator into my component and then adding it to the FormControl like the following code shows but got an error.

```
import { UniqueCompanyNameValidator } from '../../../shared/validators/custom.validators';

'company' : new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)], updateOn: 'blur' }, [UniqueCompanyNameValidator]),
```

The error that I got was the following:

```
Type 'typeof UniqueCompanyNameValidator' is not assignable to type 'AsyncValidatorFn'.
  Type 'typeof UniqueCompanyNameValidator' provides no match for the signature '(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>'.

(alias) class UniqueCompanyNameValidator
import UniqueCompanyNameValidator
```

Comment: It must be a function, not injectable token,

Comment: @Antoniossss so is the guide on the Angular official website not correct then for creating the validator? I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you are referring too.

Comment: Its correct, but what is wrong in your code is how you attach your validator. In your case you should pass the instance  as validator is a FUNCTION not an object. Most probably `[service.validate.bind(service)]` would work

Comment: to be fair the documentation is misleading and could be clearer. See my answer to know what you can do with the given class (UniqueAlterEgoValidator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be a function/validator instance, not injectable token (class/type). In your example to make it work you have to pass `validate` function, not `Service` token. Assuming that it is `this.companyService` it would be like

```
new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)], updateOn: 'blur' }, [this.comapnyService.validate.bind(this.companyService)]),
```

or maybe (I never use that variant)

```
new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)], updateOn: 'blur' }, [this.comapnyService]),
```

I would create a ValidatorFn factory method that takes required service as and argument and go from there.

```
export class MyValidators{

  static uniqueCompanyName(companyService:SompanyService){
     return (ctrl:AbstractControl)=>{
         return companyService.doCheCkeck(ctrl.value).pipe(
            map(isTaken => (isTaken ? { uniqueCompanyName: true } : null))
         );
      }
   
  }
}
```

and then

```
'company' : new FormControl(null, { validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)], updateOn: 'blur' }, [MyValidators.uniqueCompanyName(companyServiceInstance)]),
```

Comment: So this got rid of errors I was facing but now doesn't seem to ever actually trigger anything. I placed some console.log()'s into. the service and the `uniqueCompanyName` function and they never appear either.

Comment: stackblitz please then with reproduceable example.

Comment: I don't know how to do all that and make it reproduceable with the Angular Fire modules and everything. I'll just figure it out myself or go back to the old way of doing it by observing the input value and just calling the service myself. Not sure why custom validators aren't just baked into Angulars frameworks like services are.

Comment: For the benefit of the doubt, I approved your answer as you did in fact remove the error. which was the main purpose of the question. Cheers.

Comment: well to stay in angular scope (and reactive forms as this is the scope here) you can simply use observable factories like `of()` to simulate aync requests. This also allows you to isolate the problem. Best of luck

Comment: Here you have a raw example of how async validators can work and how to simulate network asynchronicty. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-47olrb?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts email is using async validator with 1500ms delay

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that the [guide you linked](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-a-custom-async-validator) is misleading for beginners. You could use the given service to create a directive which will inject UniqueAlterEgoValidator.

like so:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UniqueAlterEgoValidator implements AsyncValidator {
  constructor(private heroesService: HeroesService) {}

  validate(
    ctrl: AbstractControl
  ): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.heroesService.isAlterEgoTaken(ctrl.value).pipe(
      map(isTaken => (isTaken ? { uniqueAlterEgo: true } : null)),
      catchError(() => of(null))
    );
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MyValidatorDirective , multi: true}]
})
export class MyValidatorDirective implements AsyncValidator {

  constructor(private validator: UniqueAlterEgoValidator) {}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.validator.validate(control);
  }
}
```

**With a template driven form**: create a Directive that implements AsyncValidator.
**With a reactive form**: create a function that returns a [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn).

See the [angular guide about custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators).